# How can I use window.size to dynamically change the size of elements in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I need a way to dynamically change the size of elements as the window's size is either reduced or increased, just like the title says

```
while True:
    height, width = window.size
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'close games':
        break
    if event == 'close game':
        break
    font_size = int((height + width)/60)
    window['title'].update(font=('Stay Pixel Regular', font_size))
window.close()
```

I tried this but it didn't work and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Following code demo the option `expand_x` and `expand_y` in method `expand` of element. Of course, now you can use those option when initiate elements in your layout.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 12))
input_size1, input_size2 = (34, 1), (10, 1)
frame_filename   = [
    [sg.Text("Filename")],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column([[sg.Input("*.ppt", size=input_size1)]], pad=(0, 0)))]
]
frame_directory  = [
    [sg.Checkbox("In directory", enable_events=True, key='col1')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(
        [[sg.Input("D:\\", size=input_size1)]], pad=(0,0), key='COL1'))],
]
frame_content    = [
    [sg.Checkbox("In contents", enable_events=True, key='col2')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(
        [[sg.Input("American", size=input_size1)]], pad=(0,0), key='COL2'))],
]
frame_modify     = [
    [sg.Checkbox("Modified between", enable_events=True, key='col3')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(
        [[sg.Input("2021/01/01", size=input_size2, key='IN1'), sg.Text("-"),
          sg.Input("2021/01/14", size=input_size2, key='IN2')]],
        pad=(0,0), key='COL3'))],
]
unit = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB"]
frame_size_range = [
    [sg.Checkbox("Size range", enable_events=True, key='col4')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(
        [[sg.Input("500", size=input_size2, key='IN3'), sg.Text("-"),
          sg.Input("1000", size=input_size2, key='IN4'),
          sg.Combo(unit, unit[1], size=(4, 1), readonly=True)]],
        pad=(0,0), key='COL4'))]
]
frame_parameters = [
    [sg.Frame('', frame_filename, key='FRAME1')],
    [sg.Frame('', frame_directory, key='FRAME2')],
    [sg.Frame('', frame_content, key='FRAME3')],
    [sg.Frame('', frame_modify, key='FRAME4')],
    [sg.Frame('', frame_size_range, key='FRAME5')],
]
frame_main_search = [
    [sg.Input("*.pdf", size=input_size1, key='IN5')],
    [sg.Checkbox("All"), sg.Checkbox("Directory"), sg.Checkbox("Document"),
     sg.Checkbox("Executable"), sg.Checkbox("Picture"), sg.Checkbox("Music"),
     sg.Checkbox("Video")],
    [sg.Multiline("No files", border_width=5, key='ML')],
]
frame_top = [
    [sg.Frame('',
        [[sg.Frame('', frame_parameters, pad=(0, 0), vertical_alignment='top',
            border_width=0, key='FRAME6')]],
        vertical_alignment='top', pad=(0, 0), border_width=0),
     sg.Frame('', frame_main_search, pad=(0, 0), border_width=0, key='FRAME7')],
]
layout = [
    [sg.Frame('', frame_top, pad=(0, 0), border_width=0,
        vertical_alignment='top', key='FRAME8')],
    [sg.Frame('', [[sg.StatusBar("Status: OK", pad=(0, 0))]], pad=(0, 0),
        vertical_alignment='top', border_width=0, key='FRAME9')],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, size=(1200, 500), resizable=True,
    finalize=True)

# Expand element as window resize, it will always make element visible
for key in ['IN5', 'FRAME2', 'FRAME3', 'FRAME4', 'FRAME5', 'FRAME9']:
    window[key].expand(expand_x=True, expand_row=False)
for key in ['FRAME6']:
    window[key].expand(expand_y=True, expand_row=False)
for key in ['ML', 'FRAME7', 'FRAME8']:
    window[key].expand(expand_x=True, expand_y=True)
columns = [f'col{i+1}' for i in range(4)]

# Hide some unchecked elements
for col in columns:
    window[col.upper()].update(visible=False)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if event in columns:
        toggle = values[event]
        window[event.upper()].update(visible=toggle)

window.close()
```

Note: It will be much complex and not discussed here if you want to update the font sizes or figures in `Graph`/`Image` element, or something like this.